# Why can't I overload ostream's << operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

EDIT: Passed Expression exp and string expression by const reference

I'm trying to allow a class to be display via cout in the following manner:

```
#include <iostream>

class Expression {
private:
    std::string expression;
public:
    Expression(const std::string& expression):
        expression(expression) { }
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Expression& exp) {
        return os << exp.expression; }
};
```

however, on compiling I get the errors:

```
main.cpp(9) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream'
main.cpp(9) : error C2809: 'operator <<' has no formal parameters
```

this is especially confusing because VC++ is giving me `ostream` as an autocompletion suggestion when I enter `std::`.  What's causing these errors, and how can they be resolved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Surely you need `std::ostream` in all locations?  i.e.:

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Expression& exp) ...
                                 ^^^
```

Comment: I've tried.  It didn't solve anything, so I put back in `iostream` because I was using `cin` and `cout` elsewhere in the code, and including both was redundant.  EDIT - err, didn't see the second line.  Yeah, in retrospect, this was kind of a stupid question.

Comment: @Keand64: [Looks like the answer to me, buddy.](http://www.ideone.com/Ys2GI) Also I took the liberty of fixing your ctor parameter. Don't accept `std::string` by value.

Comment: And your `operator<<` should take `exp` by const-reference, not just by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Without a `using namespace std;` clause (which has its own set of problems), you need to fully qualify *all* the `iostream`  stuff.

You can see this with the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Expression {
private:
    std::string expression;
public:
    Expression(std::string expression):
        expression(expression) { }
    //                                  added this bit.
    //                                _/_
    //                               /   \
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Expression& exp) {
        return os << exp.expression; }
};

int main (void) {
    Expression e ("Hi, I'm Pax.");
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which prints out:

```
Hi, I'm Pax.
```

as expected.

---

And, as some comments have pointed out, you should pass the string as const-reference:

```
#include <iostream>

class Expression {
private:
    std::string expression;
public:
    Expression(const std::string& expression)
    : expression(expression) {
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Expression& exp) {
        return os << exp.expression;
    }
};

int main (void) {
    Expression e ("Hi, I'm Pax.");
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```